# IntentService registering Callbacks

Tags: android, intentservice, google-play-services

I want to use IntentService as application init component. I want it to receive the intent, call Google Play Services and do some background work after onConnected() is called. Just as Google's tutorials shows for Activity.
Is it safe to use IntentService to make a job of that kind?
I wonder because onHandleIntent is just few lines of code and all work must be done after onConnected call. So - do I understand it rightm that after finished onHandleIntent the IntentService will be destroyed and nothing will be done | NPE from callbacking service will be thrown?
Is there any possibility to keep IntentService alive as long as onConnected will be called, or should I use some BroadcastReceiver + Service pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe to use IntentService to make a job of that kind?

No. Once `onHandleIntent()` returns, the service is destroyed, if no new commands were received in the meantime. It is not safe to try to perform asynchronous operations from an `IntentService`, as not only is the *service* gone when the operation completes, but the whole *process* might be terminated (as with any background process, particularly one with no running services).

> should I use some BroadcastReceiver + Service pattern?

I don't know about the `BroadcastReceiver` part, but you are certainly welcome to use a regular `Service`. Be sure to call `stopSelf()` when your work is complete.

Comment: Thanks for `It is not safe to try to perform asynchronous operations from an IntentService.` I was desperately looking for that somewhere.

Comment: @VirendraSingh: Yes, either use `IntentService` and synchronous operations or use `Service`, asynchronous operations, and your own logic to call `stopSelf()` when all that background stuff is done.